# Apache2 not working custom domain set

Tags: networking, server, apache2, dns

so I have this problem since while ago setting up custom domain in virtualhost, It's actually working on my server unit but on my laptop its not , so I made a custom domain offline but when I'm trying to visit it it wont show it gives me `This site can't be reached.` which is a common error when the site is not accessible but when I try the `127.0.0.1` It loads the site.

here is what I set on the hosts in `/etc`:

```
0.0.0.0         customsite.app                                                                      
0.0.0.0         www.customsite.app                                                                  
127.0.0.1       customsite.app     
127.0.0.1       www.customsite.app    
# 127.0.0.1     localhost         
127.0.1.1       linuxubuntu    
                           
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts                                             
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback    
fe00::0 ip6-localnet      
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix   
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes    
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

and to my `virtualhost`:

```
<VirtualHost customsite.app:80>      
        ServerAdmin admin@django.app      
        ServerName customsite.app      
        ServerAlias www.customsite.app                                                              
        DocumentRoot /home/USER/FILES/myworkspace/Apps/python/customsite                          
        <Directory /home/USER/FILES/myworkspace/Apps/python/customsite/system/system>             
                <Files wsgi.py>                                                                        
                        Require all granted                                                            
                </Files>                                                                               
        </Directory>    
        WSGIDaemonProcess customsite.app python-path=/home/USER/FILES/myworkspace/Apps/python/customsite/system python-home=/home/USER/FILES/myworkspace/Apps/python/customsite/    
        WSGIProcessGroup n1swmsadvance.app          
        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/USER/FILES/myworkspace/Apps/python/customsite/system/system/wsgi.py                                                            
</VirtualHost>
```

and ofcourse I did this as always:

```
sudo a2ensite customesitefile.conf
sudo apachectl restart
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Try with <VirtualHost *:80> and ServerName customsite.app

Comment: I already did that @SimpliFixed.